# Adding a newline in \newtheorem

Tags: newtheorem

I'd like to define a theorem environment called `sol` in order to write solutions to exercises. I've done so through

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}[subsection]
\newtheorem*{sol}{Solution}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\alph{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi}

\begin{ex} Question
\end{ex}

\begin{sol} Solution
\end{sol}

\begin{ex} Question
   \begin{enumerate}
      \item First part
      \item Second part
   \end{enumerate}
\end{ex}

\begin{sol}
   \begin{enumerate}
      \item First part
      \item Second part
   \end{enumerate}
\end{sol}

\end{document}
```

This works fine with simple questions, but it looks a bit awkward with multipart questions (as illustrated by the previous mwe). I think it would look better if part a started in a newline rather than following the **Solution** tag. I've tried adding `\\` right after `\begin{sol}` or before or after `\begin{enumerate}`. But I get errors ("There's no line here to end").

Is there a way of adding the newline after the **Solution** tag and the list number?

Comment: Add ``\mbox{}`` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, in which you defined solution as a `newtheorem` you can proceed as in section 2.1 of [amsthm](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) manual. One way is with `\leavemode` command, but it has some problems explained in the manual.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}[subsection]
\newtheorem*{sol}{Solution}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\alph{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi}

\begin{sol}
\leavevmode
   \begin{enumerate}
      \item First part
      \item Second part
   \end{enumerate}
\end{sol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative method is to define a theorem style to perform this breaks (also from the manual):

```
\newtheoremstyle{break}%
  {}{}%
  {\itshape}{}%
  {\bfseries}{}%  % Note that final punctuation is omitted.
  {\newline}{}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trick the enumerate by adding an empty item.

```
\begin{sol}
   \begin{enumerate}
      \item[]
      \item First part
      \item Second part
   \end{enumerate}
\end{sol}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!